# Привязка картинки к карточке товара/новости

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Всем привет. Делаю сайт для диплома и столкнулся с одной проблемой.

У меня на сайте есть новостная лента, каждая новость имеет заголововк, описание, текст, дату и картинку. Занесение статьи в БД происходит из формы в административной панели сайта. Все работает как следует пока картинки просто берутся из папки на компьютере (имя картинки равняется ID новостной статьи, таким образом происходит связывание картинки со статьей).

Проблема возникает, при добавлении картинки на сервер через форму занесения новой статьи. Я не знаю как связать загружаемую картинку и текст стаьи, видел примеры в которых в поле базы данных соответствующее картинки вставляется ссылка на картинку из интернета и потом выводится в атрибут `src` тега `img`, но если картинку нужно загрузить с компьютера, то как быть?

Сейчас код вывода статьи выглядит так:

```
<?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($news); $i++){
          echo'<a href="news_topic.php?id='.$news[$i]["id"].'" class="card">
          <img src="img/news-card'.$news[$i]["id"].'.jpg" alt="" class="news-img">
          <div class="mask"></div>
          <div class="info">
            <div class="title">'.$news[$i]["title"].'</div>
            <div class="text">'.$news[$i]["desc"].'</div>
            <div class="date">'.$news[$i]["date"].'</div>
          </div>
        </a>';
        }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

если имя файла картинки привязано к ID, то при записи картинки бэкэндом на носитель, запросите у базы последний номер записи из таблицы новостей, потом увеличите его на 1 и пишите.

Comment: id сбивается при удалении новости и таким способом картинки будут путаться между записями

Comment: тогда сделайте новый столбец в таблице новостей и пишите туда рандомную строку, которая и будет именем файла. ID автоинкримент? Ничего путаться не должно, потому как ID постоянно и не меняется после удаления строки

Comment: если к примеру есть 5 записей с соответствующими ID то при удалении, к примеру, записи с ID 5 следущая созданная запись будет иметь id 6, хотя записей всего будет 5 и если поторить такое действие несколь раз то id будет во много раз превышать количесво записей по факту

Comment: так и должно быть и сделано это для целостности данных